# I am trying to get a saved image into my share latex doc

Tags: graphics

I have an image stored in my file system under the following path:

```
file:///C:/Users/jacob/Documents/Unix%20CW/ERD.png
```

I have imported the graphicx package using

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

and have declared the path:

```
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/jacob/Documents/Unix%20CW/} }
```

but when I use includegraphics

```
\includegraphics{ERD.png}
```

It says that the file cannot be found. Where have I gone wrong? I can include the rest of my code if needed.

Comment: I would expect it's due to the `%` in the file name?

Comment: I dont know why it includes the %20? In my file system that file is just called "Unix CW"

Comment: Ill try it without

Comment: - Didn't fix it

Comment: You need to upload the image if you are typesetting online. It can't use an image on your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're compiling your LaTeX in the directory where your *.tex file is, and your graphics are in the same folder, you don't need to set your graphics path